# Second `ParallelRunStep` in pipeline times out at start

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Im trying to run a sequence of more than one `ParallelRunStep` in an AzureML pipeline. To do so, I create a step with the following helper:

```
def create_step(name, script, inp, inp_ds):
    out = pip_core.PipelineData(name=f"{name}_out", datastore=dstore, is_directory=True)
    out_ds = out.as_dataset()
    out_ds_named = out_ds.as_named_input(f"{name}_out")

    config = cont_steps.ParallelRunConfig(
        source_directory="src",
        entry_script=script,
        mini_batch_size="1",
        error_threshold=0,
        output_action="summary_only",
        compute_target=compute_target,
        environment=component_env,
        node_count=2,
        logging_level="DEBUG"
    )

    step = cont_steps.ParallelRunStep(
        name=name,
        parallel_run_config=config,
        inputs=[inp_ds],
        output=out,
        arguments=[],
        allow_reuse=False,
    )

    return step, out, out_ds_named
```

As an example I create two steps like this

```
step1, out1, out1_ds_named = create_step("step1", "demo_s1.py", input_ds, named_input_ds)
step2, out2, out2_ds_named = create_step("step2", "demo_s2.py", out1, out1_ds_named)
```

Creating an experiment and submitting it to an existing workspace and Azure ML compute cluster works. Also the first step `step1` uses the `input_ds` runs its script `demo_s1.py` (which produces its output files, and finishes successfully.

However the second step `step2` never get started.

[image]

And there is a final exception

```
The experiment failed. Finalizing run...
Cleaning up all outstanding Run operations, waiting 300.0 seconds
2 items cleaning up...
Cleanup took 0.16968441009521484 seconds
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver/amlbi_main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "driver/amlbi_main.py", line 44, in main
    JobStarter().start_job()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/driver/job_starter.py", line 48, in start_job
    job.start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/driver/job.py", line 70, in start
    master.start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/driver/master.py", line 174, in start
    self._start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/driver/master.py", line 149, in _start
    self.wait_for_input_init()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/08a1e1e1-7c3f-4c5a-84ad-ca99b8a6cb31/driver/master.py", line 124, in wait_for_input_init
    raise exc
exception.FirstTaskCreationTimeout: Unable to create any task within 600 seconds.
Load the datasource and read the first row locally to see how long it will take.
Set the advanced argument '--first_task_creation_timeout' to a larger value in arguments in ParallelRunStep.
```

I have the impression, that the second step is waiting for some data. However the first step creates the supplied output directory and also a file.

```
import argparse
import os

def init():
    pass

def run(parallel_input):
    print(f"*** Running {os.path.basename(__file__)} with input {parallel_input}")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Data Preparation")
    parser.add_argument('--output', type=str, required=True)
    args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    out_path = os.path.join(args.output, "1.data")
    os.makedirs(args.output, exist_ok=True)
    open(out_path, "a").close()

    return [out_path]
```

I have no idea how to debug further. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have got this exception when my input Dataset was too large. Then mounting input at driver_70 would take hours and after init() and before run() I would get this exception.

Comment: No, I abandoned azureml in favour of azurebatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this notebook for parallel run and make sure that you are using the same packages.
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run/tabular-dataset-inference-iris.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested, you should set the "--first_task_creation_timeout" to larger value.

You can do it by:

```
argument = ["--first_task_creation_timeout", 86400]
step = ParallelRunStep(arguments = argument, ...)
```